# useMutation from react-apollo-hooks is not passing variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm refactoring my codes from `apollo-boost` to `react-apollo-hooks` and I keep getting the following errors:

```
Variable "$email" of required type "String!" was not provided
Variable "$password" of required type "String!" was not provided
```

My refactored codes are as follows:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const variables = {
    data: { email, password }
}
const login = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    variables
})

const onSubmitHandler = async (login, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const authResults = await login()
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, authResults.data.login.token);
    props.history.push('/') 
}
```

The graphql mutation

```
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(data: {
        email: $email, password: $password
        }
    ){
      token
      user {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My schema

```
login(data: LoginUserInput!): AuthPayload!
```

console.logging the email and password variables indicate that they are being properly passed to `useMutation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables in your document -- `email` and `password`. What you're actually passing to `useMutation` is a single variable called `data`, which doesn't exist.

```
const variables = { email, password }
```